# Trouble with VLOOKUP not finding data

Tags: excel, csv, vlookup

Col A has `ItemID` Col B has `Model_Num` Col C has a long list of `Model_Num`. In Col D I want to lookup the `Model_Num` of Col C and put the `ItemID`

```
item_id (colA)        model_num (colB)   to match (colC)  new data (colD)
--------              ----------         ---------        ---------
870834                FD021              KPA8A            14667122
16595156              S3TA03B            BW01B            #N/A
10752514              FD1424B            GM1500B          #N/A
10756167              SU03B              TA021            #N/A
14667130              KDAD               FD021            870834
14667122              KPA8A              FD021            870834
```

In the new data column (colD) I'm using the formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(C1,$A$1:$B$114,2,FALSE)
```

It's returning `#N/A` for everything though. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: given the data you provided it looks as though it's working.  It returns #N/A when the string in colC cannot be found in colB

Comment: No I showed what I'd like it to look like. Its retuning #N/A for everything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a mistake in your VLOOKUP formula and/or the way your data is organized by column. VLOOKUP can not be used to look up values to the left of the lookup value in the VLOOKUP table - you would have to use an INDEX/MATCH function to do that - or you could just do this.

1) You could cut and insert your column A(item_iD) to the right of your current column B(model_num). Then adjust your VLOOKUP formula appropriately. (So basically your item_id and model_num columns are backwards currently).

If you want to keep your column order "as is" then you will need to use an INDEX/MATCH function which I can certainly provide:

```
=INDEX($A$1:$B$114,MATCH(C1,$B$1:$B$114,0),1)
```

Leave your data as is and put that in the top cell column D and then autofill down. It should give you what you want.

Good Luck.

Comment: Just for reference, if I switched the column A(item_ID) and column B(model_num) I still can't get my VLOOKUP to work. Same senario as above with the columns switched like you suggested.

Comment: I would do a quick review of VLOOKUP to make sure you understand how to use it. However, assuming you are using it correctly, another common issue with VLOOKUP is that the cell formatting needs to be the same in your lookup column as it is for your lookup cell. For example if your model_number column is formatted as text and your lookup value cell is formatted as a number then VLOOKUP will have trouble matching them up.